# Regex pattern not being detected properly in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a specific pattern I want to follow but the extraction process is not working as expected. I assume the pattern I developed is not correct, but I can't find the issue in it.

I have the string `string test1 = "R1 0.1uF"` and the pattern

`"(?<des>^[a-zA-Z]+)|(?<number>\d+\s+)|(?<val>[0-9]*.?[0-9]+)|(?<units>[^,]*)";`

I want it to be extracted as follows:

des: R

number: 1

val: 0.1

units: uF

Currently, `des` is working properly and it's finding `R` but the others return an empty string.

Here's my code

```cs
const string pattern = @"(?<des>^[a-zA-Z]+)|(?<number>\d+\s+)|(?<val>[0-9]*.?[0-9]+)|(?<units>[^,]*)";

string test1 = "R1 0.1uF";

Regex r = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled);

Match m = r.Match(test1);
string des = m.Groups["des"].Value;
string number = m.Groups["number"].Value;
string val = m.Groups["val"].Value;
string units = m.Groups["units"].Value;
```

Comment: Why are you joining the parts with `|`? That means "OR" -- it's matching the `des` bit, and then because that matched, it's not trying any of the other bits

Comment: My bad, I completely overlooked that. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You could remove the `|` and make it a bit more specific `^(?<des>[a-zA-Z]+)(?<number>[0-9]+)\s+(?<val>[0-9](?:\.[0-9]+)?)(?<units>[^,]*)`

Comment: Try following : const string pattern = @"(?<des>[a-zA-Z]+)(?<number>[^\s]+)\s(?<val>[0-9]*.?[0-9]+)(?<units>.*)";

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two comments:

1. Remove all the `|`s because you don't want to match `des OR number OR val OR units` but `des followed by number followed by val followed by units`
2. Escape the dot: `\.` because you want to match a dot, not some random character.

So, your regex becomes

```
(?<des>^[a-zA-Z]+)(?<number>\d+\s+)(?<val>[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)(?<units>[^,]*)
```

Look at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/VoDTis/1)

Some little improvements, if I may:

- Move the caret `^` to the front. It doesn't belong in the first group.
- Do not capture the space(s) in the group number.

Like this:

```
^(?<des>[a-zA-Z]+)(?:(?<number>\d+)\s+)(?<val>[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)(?<units>[^,]*)
```

See [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/VoDTis/2)